# Inner div's margin affecting containing div's margin

Tags: html, css

I have an inner div inside a containing div.

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
#inner {
    margin: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8xUTJ/4/

I expect this to make a small black box centered vertically and horizontally in a bigger red box.  Instead I get a black box stuck to the top of the red box, and the red box has the margin-top.

Can someone explain what CSS thinks it is doing here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to the `#container` div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8xUTJ/6/)**

Or

add a border to the `#container` div.

You can read more about this collapsing margin behavior at the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Comment: Is there some hidden reasoning to this super-strange CSS "margin collapse" logic??? It seems like the most counter-intuitive behaviour I've encountered, and I bet millions of developers have fallen into this pit and have tried unnecessary workarounds like `padding`, `overflow` etc., causing unnecessary side-effects... Excuse my bluntness, but sometimes it seems CSS is one of the stupidest languages around.

Answer (score 15):

While the solutions provided are viable, nobody explains the problem.  It's called margin collapsing which happens in several scenarios.

Scenario 1 - these items will only be 30px apart, because the margins collapse together and the larger one prevails.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 30px"></div>
```

Scenario 2 - (your scenario) the margin of the inner box spills outside of the outer box.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
</div>
```

The solution is to give the outer box some padding or a border (as suggested by others).  Often times, I use the following CSS on the outer box to mitigate situations like this:

```
.outer {
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: @j08691 An explanation **here** is always better than a bare link.

Comment: @toscho - if brief sure, but there's no point in pasting the entire explanation of collapsing margins when a link will suffice. Plus I'm pretty sure the W3C isn't going away anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

**method 1**

`position:absolute` for the inner div, so it *knows* **what** to be 30px margin from

http://jsfiddle.net/8xUTJ/5/

---

**method 2**

`display:inline-block` for the inner div

http://jsfiddle.net/8xUTJ/7/

---

**method 3**

`border:solid 0 transparent` to outer div

http://jsfiddle.net/8xUTJ/8/

*Take your pick :)*

Answer (score 2):

First, `#container` has `margin-top:0` and `#inner` has `margin-top:30px`. The relationship of these elements is that of a parent and a first child.

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to
>   separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Margin collapsing means *these margins are combined into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it*

> These rules apply even to margins that are zero, so the margin of a
>   first/last child ends up outside its parent (according to the rules
>   above) whether or not the parent's margin is zero

This is why you end up with 30px top margin applied outside of the `#container` element, from your fiddle:

[image: 30px and 0 top margins collapse]

Answer (score 1):

check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xUTJ/9/)

You need to `float` the inner `div` to make it work

```
#inner {    
    margin:30px;
    float:left;   /* give float */
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
 }​
```

Or else give `overflow:auto` property to the `div#container`.

check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xUTJ/10/)