# Vertically centering children with a common parent

Tags: css

I have a parent div with several children http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/FUqSP/ and i wish to vertically center each div inside a child within that containing child.For instance i would like to center **child_two** in **child_one**.I have this css

```
.parent{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:orange;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.child_one{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:purple;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.child_two{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:pink;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.child_three{
width:25px;
height:25px;
background-color:yellow;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.child_four{
width:12px;
height:12px;
background-color:red;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

and this is the html

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child_one">
<div class="child_two">
<div class="child_three">
<div class="child_four">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: read this:http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/  it is presented some good ways to achieve centering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/FUqSP/3)

I used `float:left;` to achieve it.

check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/FUqSP/6/)

which i have done using percentages.
For other methods to achieve this check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632144/1577396)

I recommend you to do this with percentages. which do not make you confuse.

Comment: you should come up with a square illusion formula :). Your solution works but i don't understand why you float:left.

Comment: so that the margin:top should be considered by its parent div. You can also use `overflow:hidden`. I am trying that :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this on each child

position: relative;
top: 25%;

Here the full css,

```
.parent{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:orange;
display:table-cell;

 }
.child_one{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:purple;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 position: relative;
top: 25%;
}
.child_two{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:pink;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 position: relative;
top: 25%;
}
.child_three{
width:25px;
height:25px;
background-color:yellow;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 position: relative;
top: 25%;
}
.child_four{
width:12px;
height:12px;
background-color:red;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 position: relative;
top: 25%;
}
```

Here the DEMO: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUqSP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning of the childs. You have to position each child at top 50% and left 50% and give them a negative top and left margin of half it's width and height.

```
.parent{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:orange;
    position: relative;
}
.child_one{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:purple;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

This is just the first child. You have to do the same on each child. So if the width is 50px, use a margin of -25px.

http://jsfiddle.net/APdaP/

Answer (score 0):

According to the link I sent you in my previous comment, you should try the solution called:

**Css Table Method**.

It will display your divs as table cells so that you can use `vertical-align` for your children divs.