# Align vertical and horizontal a fixed div with relative sizes

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, css, alignment

I ask this question  because it is making me crazy due it is shown properly on chrome browsers but not in Firefox/IE.

I want a div which it must be aligned vertically and horizontally according to the window. It also has relative sizes. Can you please help me ? I've tried this but it only works on Chrome:

```
    #itemNewsFS {
       position:fixed;
       display:none;
       width: 50%;
       left: 50%; 
       margin-left: -25%;
       height: 80%;
       top: 50%;
       margin-top: -40%;
    }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margins (both vertical and horizontal) are calculated relatively to the **width** of the containing box, read this extract from the CSS2.1 specification: [little link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties).

To achieve what you want, you can keep your `margin-left` value, but you'll have to use JavaScript to fix `margin-top`:

```
document.getElementById("itemNewsFS").style.marginTop = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 40 / 100) + "px";
```

Comment: I think we can also use `overflow:auto;` or `float` instead of `javascript`? pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I know how to do it with JavaScript, I tried to find a CSS code to do it

Comment: @themazz You can't. Did you read the CSS specification extract? If you want to vertically center a `position: fixed;` element with relative `height`, then this is the only way to go.

Comment: @Mr_Green Can you explain more?

Comment: @Abody97 I can provide you a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12632144/1577396) which may be the same problem as this is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it:

```
<div class="block">
   <div id="itemNewsFS">
       Unknown stuff to be centered.
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.block {
    text-align: center;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 100%; /* Put your height here */
}

.block:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */

}

#itemNewsFS {
display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}​
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/